# Graphite graph background

Tags: graphite

I have installed graphite locally and it is running fine. When I opened graphite-web, it is showing some red and black background image as show in the image, which not supposed to be.

[image]

Could you please help me how to remove this black background?

Comment: I don't see any read but that black stuff looks like the numbers on the axis with a very large font.

Comment: You are right. thanks Andreas.